# Animating a long value

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to animate a `long` value using a ValueAnimator. The `ValueAnimator` doesn't have an `.ofLong(long... values)` builder. What is the best way to achieve this? Casting the longs to an `int` doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm currently facing the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while building a scrolling time based view with scroll position as a long value of milliseconds. I ended up refactoring to use an int value of seconds, but if that is not appropriate for you here is my original solution. If you are using very large longs, the multiplying with floats and casting back to longs may cause inaccuracies, but give it a shot...

```
    // There is a long somewhere that needs to be animated. Let's call it valueToAnimate
    // This assumes it's a millisecond value for a time based scrolling view.
    // Make a final copy of it for the animator
    final long startValue = valueToAnimate;
    // Also make a final reference to the target long for the animator
    final long finishValue = valueToAnimate + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; // animate to 2 weeks from now
    // Calculate distance needed to travel
    final long distance = finishValue - startValue;
    // Create a ValueAnimator of floats from 0 through to 1.
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            long valueToAnimate = startValue + (long) (distance * (float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // Make sure you end on the correct value
            valueToAnimate = finishValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```